# Monodroid hiding and showing the status bar

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

As the title states I would like to hide the status bar in my android app.

I know how this is done in android but with monodroid I am not to sure..

Any suggestions would be great. I was thinking of having an option menu to hide and show it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the same way as in android ...

in activity

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); //to show
this.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); //to hide
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried that but it didn't work before but now it works. Thanks again :)